# Recoger datos en articulo de joomla, usando php y fabrik

Tags: php

Intento ver una imagen y un `nombre_establecimiento` elemento de fabrik, usando php en Joomla.
Veo el nombre, pero no la imagen. creo que el código de la imagen no debe estar bien
la ruta de la imagen es:

> images/stories/969/imagen-1.png

Donde 969 es el `user_id` del usuario
y el código que he puesto es:

```
<p>&nbsp;{source}&lt;?php</p>
<p>$user =&amp; JFactory::getUser();<br />$userId = $user-&gt;get( 'id' );</p>
<p>$db = JFactory::getDbo();<br />$query = $db-&gt;getQuery(true);</p>
<p>//echo $userId;</p>
<p>$query-&gt;select($db-&gt;quoteName(array('nombre_establecimiento', 'user_id',)))</p>
<p>-&gt;from($db-&gt;quoteName('insertar_logo'))</p>
<p>-&gt;where($db-&gt;quoteName('user_id') . ' = ' . $userId);</p>
<p>$db-&gt;setQuery($query);</p>
<p>$results = $db-&gt;loadAssocList();</p>
<p>foreach ($results as $rows) {
<br />echo "&lt;center&gt;";<br />
echo "<img src='images/stories/" . $userId . "/image-1.png'>";
echo "&lt;H1&gt;" . $rows['nombre_establecimiento'] . "&lt;/H1&gt;" . "&lt;BR&gt;";<br />echo "&lt;/center&gt;";</p>
<p>}<br />?&gt;{/source}</p>
```

en Joomla me devuelve el `nombre_establecimiento`, pero no me devuelve la imagen  y tampoco da error.

alguna sugerencia??

Gracias!!

Javier

Comment: echo "<img src='images/stories/" . $userId . "/image-1.png'>";    (este primer echo no lo ha puesto el codigo solo echo"" por lo que igual hay un error

Comment: Tienes demasiado lío en tu código, en la línea siguiente a la que mencionas tienes otro `echo` perdido casi al final ... sugiero que limpies un poco el código por ejemplo trabajando todo en un bloque PHP concatenando todo en una sola variable y luego haciendo `echo` una sola vez de esa variable.

Comment: supongo que hay lio, si no tengo ni idea.. de php.. es el problema, he podido hacer esto y funciona casi, me falta ver la imagen.. no se si lo de $userid está bien o mal, o habria que poner otra cosa

Comment: Para probar crea una variable sólo con esto: `$img="<img src='images/stories/" . $userId . "/image-1.png'>";` y luego la pruebas con `var-dump($img);` así revisas si está bien. Además, tienes el `query` dentro de código HTML, dudo que eso pueda funcionar de ese modo.